# PHP SoapClient "Body must be present in a SOAP envelope" error

Tags: php, exception, soap, wsdl

I faced with very strange issue when tried to use PHP SoapClient for this service http://bws.neteven.com/NWS/2.

I have to setup an authentication header. Request body should be empty. The code, which I used is below:

```
    $client = new SoapClient("http://bws.neteven.com/NWS/2", array("trace" => 1, "exception" => 1));
    $auth = array(//the params are not valid of course
        'Method' => 'TestConnection',
        'Login' => 'login',
        'Seed' => 'seed',
        'Stamp' => 'stamp',
        'Signature' => 'signature'
    );
    $client->__setSoapHeaders(new SoapHeader('auth', 'AuthenticationHeader', $auth));
    $client->__soapCall('TestConnection',array(null));
```

After that I used $client->__getLastRequest() to see what is final XML of the request. However I can see that the header and body params were not setup properly. 
$client->__getLastRequest() outputs plain text like this:

```
MethodTestConnectionLoginloginSeedseedStampstampSignaturesignature
```

Which doesn't look like valid XML. So of course I get SoapFault exception with the text "Body must be present in a SOAP envelope".

Does anybody knows why header and body are not wrapped by required XML tags?

Any issue in the code? Because I saw lots of examples of PHP SoapClient usage with the same approach. In addition I tried a few test WSDL services and had valid requests and responses there.

Could it be a problem of provided WSDL schema?

Or a problem of my server configuration? I use PHP 5.6.3, php_soap extension is enabled.

Hope you guys can help me. Any your thoughts would be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: When you echo `$client->__getLastRequest()` look in the browser source code, what you're seeing sounds right to me (text wrapped with xml elements on a html output)

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you. The XML looks valid. Why I didn't realize to do that?:)

OK, just 1 main problem remains: why I get SoapFault exception instead of response?

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:NWS:examples" xmlns:ns2="auth"><SOAP-ENV:Header><ns2:AuthenticationHeader><item><key>Method</key><value>TestConnection</value></item><item><key>Login</key><value>login</value></item><item><key>Seed</key><value>seed</value></item><item><key>Stamp</key><value>stamp</value></item><item><key>Signature</key><value>signature</value></item></ns2:AuthenticationHeader></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:TestConnectionRequest/></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>`

Comment: Hey I found this example https://gist.github.com/benedict-w/4604789

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code example I found has a different URL...

`http://bws.neteven.com/NWS/2` vs `http://ws.neteven.com/NWS`

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://ws.neteven.com/NWS", array("trace" => 1, "exception" => 1));
$auth = array(//the params are not valid of course
    'Method' => 'TestConnection',
    'Login' => 'login',
    'Seed' => 'seed',
    'Stamp' => 'stamp',
    'Signature' => 'signature'
);
$client->__setSoapHeaders(new SoapHeader('auth', 'AuthenticationHeader', $auth));
$client->__soapCall('TestConnection',array(null));
```

Also, you can call methods like this without using `__soapCall` (even though it would be doing the same thing).

```
$result = $client->echo(array("EchoInput" => "ReturnMe"));
var_dump($result->EchoOutput);

$result = $client->TestConnection();
var_dump($result->TestConnectionResult);
```

Comment: Yeah, it works with "ws".
Thank you Scuzzy. Really appreciate your help.